# Bootstrap 3 navbar - Change font color on action link dynamicallly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the font color for the action link for the current page dynamically, so that the link for the current page is highlighted.

Is there a way to do that relatively easily?

Comment: You need to tell that link that it is "active" via html/php and style it accordingly by giving it a special class.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `active` class to your `class=` of your link. So it looks like `class="active"`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That works. To do it dynamically, I had to assign an id to link first.

Comment: <li>@Html.ActionLink("Assembly S/N", "Index", "Home", null, new { @id = "IndexLink" })</li>

and then

$("#IndexLink").addClass("activeLink");